# Permissions error when retrieving Coursework resource from Google Classroom as a Domain Admin

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

I have a Google script to get a list of all Google Classrooms in our edu domain along with all of the assignments ("Coursework") in each Classroom.  Running this as the Google domain admin, I can get the list of classrooms, but attempting to get the list of assignments results in a "caller does not have permission" error.  Do Google domain admins not have rights to get the list of assignments?  Do I need to include some special authentication method here?

```
function listCourses() {
  var optionalArgs = {
    pageSize: 20
  };
  var response = Classroom.Courses.list(optionalArgs);
  var courses = response.courses;

  if (courses && courses.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
      var course = courses[i];
      Logger.log('%s , %s , %s , %s ', course.name, course.id, course.ownerId, course.creationTime);

      var id = course.id;
      // the error "caller does not have permission" occurs here:
      var coursework = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.list(id)
      var arr=[];
      if (coursework && coursework.length > 0) {
        for (k = 0; k < coursework.length; k++) {
          var cw = coursework[k]; 
          var ids = cw.id;
          var user = cw.creatorUserId;
          var type = cw.workType;
          var ti = cw.title;
          var des = cw.description;
          var st = cw.state;
          var sch = cw.scheduledTime;
          var due = cw.dueDate;
          Logger.log('%s , (%s) , %s , %s', user, ti, des, due);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This issue was discussed in the [issue tracker](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/36765087). This ticket was already filed, you can follow the thread for the updates.

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 The link requires to sign-in to MOMA, in other words is not accessible to non-googlers.

Comment: Per the other answer, your automatic scopes may not have updated properly. If you access them via `File->Properties-> Scopes`, what is shown?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on a script that needs to do the same thing and I ran into this exact issue.

In the Apps script editor menu choose **View->Show manifest file**
which opens a file named **appsscript.json**
In this file,  add the JSON property `oauthScopes` and set it to an array of authorization request URLs like this:

```
"oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.students.readonly",
                 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses.readonly"
               ]
```

After this I had to republish my webapp as a new version and click to accept the new permissions, but now I can get a list of all coursework for a particular student.

Resources:

[https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/auth](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-coursework)
https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-coursework

Comment: What were the automatic scopes prior to you specifying them explicitly? (I.e. if you remove that section from the manifest, then go to `File->Properties`, what is in the Scopes tab?)

Comment: For some reason no scopes were added automatically. You are not prompted to accept anything. It just throws the error "caller does not have permission" as @Duane mentioned. I found this issue in the [public bug tracker too](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73787779)

Comment: Seems like a bug in the oAuth scope detection then :) Good find, shame I didn't think of it sooner for OP (it's a logical step to go from "invalid permissions" -> "what permissions did it ask for")